# How to install older versions of Intel c++ compiler using apt

Tags: c++, icc, intel-oneapi, icx

I want to install Intel C++ compiler version 17, 18, 19 using apt package management tool.
I searched on the official Intel website, but i can't find how to install older versions.

There are explanation and list about recent version of compilers. ([link](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneapi-ci/))
Can you explain the way to install the versions i want?

Comment: Do you have licenses for those versions? This may help: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/troubleshooting/older-version-product.html

Comment: Thanks for reply! 
No, i don't have.  Is the license necessary for me to use old Intel compiler? and how do i get one?

Comment: Generally, licenses were required for older versions. You could either buy them or, in some specific cases, you could obtain them for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Intel oneAPI Toolkits are open source, you can download them for free. Please find the below links for downloading the latest Intel Base and HPC Toolkits. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit-download.html https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/hpc-toolkit-download.html

To access older releases you need a version that includes Intel Priority Support, the free versions do not include this. Here is a link to the online store to get a commercially supported version. Please find the below link: https://softwarestore.intel.com/